# Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry

Can the following Trigonometric equation be solved using the Unit Circle or a Right Angled Triangle. I know how to solve using Double angled formula.

> Solve $\cos(2A)=\dfrac{1}{9}$ and give your answer in the form of $\pm  \sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers.

Comment: This is not possible, $\arccos^21/9$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\cos(2A) = 2\cos^2(A)-1$ we have $2\cos^2(A)-1 = \frac 1 9$;
Adding 1 to each side gives us $2\cos^2(A) = \frac {10}{9}$; then dividing by 2 we get $\cos^2(A) = \frac 5 9$.
Taking the square roots of both sides we have $\cos(A) = \sqrt \frac 5 9$.

Conversely, using $\cos(2A) = 1-\sin^2(A)$ we get $1-2\sin^2(A)=\frac 1 9$
Flipping around the $\sin (A)$ and the $\frac 1 9$ we have $2\sin^2(A)=\frac 8 9$;
dividing by 2 again we have $\sin^2(A)=\frac 4 9$; then taking square roots we have $\sin(A) = \sqrt \frac 4 9$.

If we use the identity $\sin^2(A) + \cos^2(A) = 1$, these two values will check out.